# Joomla 2.5 JHtml::_('sliders in frontend and ie7

Tags: joomla, internet-explorer-7, slider

breaking my head on this problem:

I'm using Joomla! 2.5.8 and Virtuemart 2.0.14 and I'm loading the Joomla-internal slide-effect

`<?php echo JHtml::_('sliders.start', 'my-slider', array('useCookie'=>'0', 'startOffset'=>-1));`

into frontend.

It works as it should - except in IE7 (i don't care about IE6 anymore).
Well, the same code is used in joomla-backend, and there it is working in ie7.

Link to have a look at: http://shop.restaurants-schoengruen.ch/weine.html

The slides can be found here, directly above add-to-cart-button (in den Warenkorb): Detailinformationen zum Produkt

BTW: tried it with `jquery` (google-apis); worked fine for the sliders, but the add-to-cart-message in vm-facebox didn't work anymore.

I hope someone can provide me some help; why is joomla jhtml-slider not working on ie7 in frontend.

Comment: ... meant this code;hope it's complete now...

 JHtml::_('sliders.start', 'my-slider', array('useCookie'=>'0', 'startOffset'=>-1));

Comment: Can you tell what does happen in IE7, e.g. errors in the browser etc, Javascript errors...

Comment: the first slider on the page is working, the other slide is opened and can't be changed; tried it with different slider-ids, but no effect. i don't get any errors in browser.

Comment: hi, i abandoned jhtml-sliders and was using this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527829/mootools-accordion-not-working). works with mootools, too, but also on ie7.

Comment: I'm curious that you don't get any errors... you do have IE7's developer toolbar installed... right? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359